# Working CartoCSS editor?

Tags: style, tilemill, cartocss

I set up my own tile server starting with the [switch2osm tutorial](https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/) to which I added contour lines and hillshading. It is based on openstreetmap-carto which is obviously CartoCSS, but when I tried to find a way to edit the styling faster and easier I noticed that TileMill is pretty much abandoned and that most modern tools output JSON.

Is it worth sticking to CartoCSS, (if yes, please recommend a working editor), or shall I switch to the newer JSON based styling?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply edit the style files in any text editor. You can use Kosmtik to quickly see your changes.

Comment: Thanks. I stumbled upon Kosmtik before but didn't really understand what it does so I ignored it. I tried it out now, generating mapnik.xml from project.mml still takes a lot of time, but it is indeed more user friendly to click around than issue commands. I haven't had an indepth look at the inspector yet.

Comment: Kosmtik can also directly read the .mml. It still will take some time to parse (perhaps about half a minute, depending on your machine), on every change. This would be the same in TileMill.